# PugiXML Preserve Whitespace, but not EOL

Tags: html-parsing, whitespace, eol, pugixml

I'm converting html into xml, changing tag names and other stuff, but i have problems with preserving whitespaces.
This is how I'm loading file:

```
xml_parse_result check = doc.load_file(sourcePath.c_str(), (parse_default | parse_ws_pcdata), encoding_auto);
```

But if I use it that way, also '\n' and '\r' are preserved. I can't understant why, because parse_escapes and parse_eol are on by default.

parse_ws_pcdata_single, doesn't fit me, because whitespaces I wan't to preserve have sibling.

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and output file that you're getting right now without changing the content?

Comment: for example, input:
    <parent>
     <tag>some text
     <tag_child1>some text 2</tag_child1> <tag_child1>some text3</tag_child1></tag>
    </parent>

When parsing, i'm getting this thing:
root: parent
 first_child: \n
  next_sibling: tag

It saves single whitespace, but also assuming \n as child node. 
I was trying to preserve whitespace and not getting \n or \r

But I've already solved the poblem by pre-parsing file, deleting all unwanted characters. I believe there is a better solution.